# Run PowerShell [System.windows.forms.messagebox] through a Batch file without cmd window showing

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

I am trying to create an automated process that will clean user data on every login to a laptop. The main parts are finished and I am in the polishing phase. I have two batch files run on startup that cleans user data from the profile being logged into and they both work. My issue comes with the the cmd window that appears behind my dialogue box (See picture).

[image: cmd and dialogue box]

Researching how to get this cmd box to be invisible lead me to VBS. I did find a solution for that, but now the dialogue box does not show at all. I believe it is probably because the VBS script is making all windows prompts invisible.

Bottom line is, how can I get my dialogue box to appear without the CMD window opening with it?

The VBScript is currently running under the common startup folder here:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

*Deletion script:*

```
@echo off

::Set color of script
color 0a

::Title
title Loaner data wipe
set userpreserve="Administrator,All Users,Default,Public,barfiej"

::All files and folders within the parent folders below will be deleted.
c:
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Contacts\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Links\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Music\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive - Six Continents Hotels, Inc\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Saved Games\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Searches\*"
del /S /F/ Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Videos\*"

::Clear credential manager
For /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do cmdkey /delete %H
```

*Dialogue box cmd:*

```
powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; C:\ProgramData\LoanerBatchFile\dialogue_box.ps1;"
```

*dialogue_box.ps1:*

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("Welcome to your loaner computer.

`nPlease keep the follow the following instructions while using the loaner laptop.

`n- Save all documents to OneDrive. Data is set to be removed from the user profile at each logoff

`n- Use Webmail

`n- Please keep the computer clean

`n- Be sure to return loaner when picking up your computer");
```

*VBS script:*

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\ProgramData\LoanerBatchFile\UserDataDeletion.bat" & Chr(34), 0
WshShell.Run chr(34) & objShell.Run("C:\ProgramData\LoanerBatchFile\dialogue.bat") & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Why are you calling the external stuff when what you are doing can be done all in PowerShell? Lastly, you are using PowerShell to call 2 external executables, cmd.exe explicitly and cscript.exe implicitly. So, cmd.exe is supposed to show, since you are implicitly calling cscript.exe to run VBS stuff and UI stuff, like setting windows titles and the like. Why do that, if you don't want it seen? Set a logon scheduled task to run your script.

Comment: Why not just change your `Dialog box cmd` to this:`@"%__AppData__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\ProgramData\LoanerBatchFile\dialogue_box.ps1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the alternative way:

```
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell 
[Void]$wsh.PopUp("Message content here")
```

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to my initial comment above.

Untested, because I've nothing to test this concept on, but, roughly something like...

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

& cmd.exe set userpreserve="Administrator,All Users,Default,Public,barfiej"

# All files and folders within the parent folders below will be deleted.

'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Contacts\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Favorites\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Links\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Music\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\OneDrive - Six Continents Hotels, Inc\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Pictures\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Saved Games\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Searches\*',
'C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Videos\*' | 
ForEach { Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -Recurse -Force}

<#
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rmilne/script-to-clear-credman
#>

& cmd.exe For /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %G in ('cmdkey /list ^| findstr Target') do cmdkey /delete %H

[System.windows.forms.messagebox]::show(
"Welcome to your loaner computer.
`nPlease keep the follow the following instructions while using the loaner laptop.
`n- Save all documents to OneDrive. Data is set to be removed from the user profile at each logoff
`n- Use Webmail
`n- Please keep the computer clean
`n- Be sure to return loaner when picking up your computer"
)
```

Again, put this in logon/startup scheduled task assigned to RunOnce, or at logon.